# Adding Flow type checking to Webpack, Babel & Eslint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, flowtype

I have a Webpack 4 config file that compiles ES6 React code to ES5 using Babel (plus stage 3 preset and some optimisation plugins). It lints the code with Eslint.

```
import path from 'path';


export default {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './app/app.jsx',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'app.js',
    publicPath: '/dist/js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'stage-3', 'react'],
          plugins: [
            'babel-plugin-styled-components',
            'transform-react-remove-prop-types',
            'transform-react-inline-elements',
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Now I want to add Flow type checking to my project but I can't find ANY good full examples of how a config setup like this should look.

I've tried adding [eslint-plugin-flow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-flowtype) to the Eslint config. I've tried adding [babel-preset-flow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-flow) to the Babel presets. I always end up getting errors either about needing an appropriate loader to handle the files, or it complains that my Flow code is invalid.

Note my config works before adding Flow. Can anyone show how to add Flow?

Comment: Most people just have an `npm` script for `flow` that they run from the command line. If you want to integrate it within your Webpack build step, you can use something like [flowtype-loader](https://github.com/torifat/flowtype-loader).

Comment: @saadq If I did it as an npm script, would I have to manually run it very time I want to do type checking? The benefit of the Webpack integration is that I can get it working with a live reload server to watch and recompile files on change.

Comment: Yes, you would need to run it manually each time. Most people have editor plugins for Flow so that they see type errors right in their code editor, and then they just run `flow` from the command line if they want to see more detailed error messages.